# Generators K-theory of Cuntz algebras

Tags: reference-request, oa.operator-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology

The Cuntz algebra $O_n$ is the C*-algebra generated by n isometries $S_1$, ..., $S_n$ such that $S_i^* S_j=\delta_{i,j}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^nS_iS_i^*=1$. Cuntz proved that this algebra has the following K-theory: $K_0(O_n)=\mathbb{Z}_{n-1}$, $K_1(O_n)=0$. Does any one know what are the generators of $K_0(O_n)$ ($n\geq 3$)?

Comment: I think it should correspond to the idempotent s_1s_1*

Comment: @  Benjamin Steinberg: I am not sure. Probably I am wrong, but S_S_1^* is equivalent to 1 (S_1 is an isometry). However, the class of [1] is 0.

Comment: Yes you are right it is equivalent to 1. But isn't the class of 1 the generator not 0 for n>2?  All n of those idempotents are equivalent to 1 so the cuntz relation gives n[1]=[1].

Comment: Ok. So we can choose 1, and say that it is a generator of the K_0 group. Could you give me a reference or expand your comment in an answer that proves that the class of 1 is not zero? Thank you for the help

Comment: I am not sure where to find a reference for the operator case. You can find this for Leavitt path algebras in the survey of Abrams on the first decade of Leavitt path algebras. I am sure the operator theory proof is essentially the same but as an algebraist I wouldn't know how to write it in a technically correct way.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I'll read Abrams' paper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is answered on the first page of Cuntz's paper "K-Theory for Certain C*-Algebras" (*Ann. of Math.* **113** (1981), 181-197). If you google "cuntz algebra k-theory" it is the first result.